# Issues rendering Unordered List inside of an Anchor tag

Tags: jquery, css, html

For some reason the unordered list I have inside of an anchor tag is rendering outside of it in inspector and thus a script that I'm trying to write to target it is not working because it does not see it as being inside of the anchor tag.

I am using html5 because I know that was a limitation previously in that only inline elements could be displayed inside anchor tags, but I'm having this issue.

This is what my html looks like...

```
<a class="about-us topitem <?php if($section == 'about-us'){?>active open<?php };?>" style="background-position: left 13px">About Us
    <ul class="subnav about" data-height="92">
        <li><a class="subitem" href="what-to-expect.php">What to Expect</a>
```

I could really use some help here, I've not been able to find much through googling.

Comment: Can you add the generated HTML too.

Comment: Why would you have an `a` inside a `li` inside a ``ul` inside a `a`?

Comment: You cannot wrap anchor tag inside an other anchor tag

Comment: [**Nested Links are illegal**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.2.2) when you set an `a` tag it close at the first `</a>` tag he finds... doesn't matter if another `a` tag was open after.

Comment: It's for a nested navigation but it is a very complicated one and it seems I need to re think how this works, it's weird because on desktop certain links show up and then the page has an inner navigation, and on mobile that inner nav disappears and is supposed to show up under the sub navigation in the main nav